# String matching between two columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, string-matching

I have a dataframe (df) containing the "Address" and "District" and "State" as three columns:

Input:

```
Address                                  District       State
132, 1st block, Mysore,Karnataka         Mysore        Karnataka
24, 4th Block, Jayanagar India           Bangalore     Karnataka
Prestige owen, M.G Road                  Bangalore     Karnataka
Opp: Reliance trend, Mantri Mall,-Delhi  New Delhi     New Delhi
```

Basically I want to flag (as new column) the rows where the entity under column "District" is present in under Address column,

Expected output:

```
Address                             District    State     Dist_match 
132, 1st block, Mysore,Karnataka    Mysore      Karnataka  TRUE
24, 4th Block, Jayanagar India      Bangalore   Karnataka  FALSE
Prestige owen, M.G Road             Bangalore   Karnataka  FALSE
Opp: Reliance trend, 
Mantri Mall,-Delhi                 New Delhi    New Delhi  TRUE
```

I tried the following but got warnings and it didn't work well

```
 df$Dist_match  <- mapply(grepl, pattern=df$District, x=df$Address)
```

Comment: why there is `#` on the first two rows?

Comment: @Pascal its correct, Removed it to avoid confusion

Comment: It is working for me (based on the example provided) `mapply(grepl, pattern=df$District, x=df$Address)#
   Mysore Bangalore Bangalore New Delhi 
     TRUE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE`

Comment: For this case  address: "CHOWK, MAUNATH BHANJAN DIST,MAU -220187"  and District: "MAU" the code return "FALSE"

Comment: and what is the pattern there?

Comment: @akrun Shouldn't the last value be `TRUE` ??

Comment: @akrun: I am not sure if I follow you but The keyword "pattern" is part of the syntax.                                          In this case the pattern is, for say 1st row, match the entry under column "District" and "Address"

Comment: @RonakShah Based on the input data, there is only `-Delhi` in the last row for address

Comment: @akrun ohkk..the output string is something different. OP please check.

Comment: @RonakShah, yes Akrun is correct!, the expected output must be as the given input